# The best solution of method dependency

Tags: java, android

I am wondering if there is any solution for method dependency of this object and the supper object. I am now working in android, and overriding the `onBackPressed` method.

I have created a class called `ActivityContainer`, used to handle universal behaviors. the logic of the `onBackPressed`  of this class is

1. Close the menu if the menu is currently opening
2. Prompt if going to close the app, yes to close, no or no action to stay

Then, I have an other class called `FragmentActivityContainer` extends `ActivityContainer`, used to handle universal behaviors that used in fragment. the logic of the `onBackPressed` of this class id

1. Close the menu if the menu is currently opening
2. Back the previous fragment if changed fragments in content area
3. Prompt if going to close the app, yes to close, no or no action to stay

the dependency is messy. Let's take a look for `ActivityContainer` first

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(this.menu != null && this.menu.isShowing()){
        this.menu.close();
    }  else {
        this.promptQuite();
    } 
}
```

nice and clear, works fine.

Let's have a look for `FragmentActivityContainer`

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(this.menu != null && this.menu.isShowing()){
            this.menu.close();
        }  else if(this.fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
            super.getParent().onBackPressed();
        } else{
            this.promptQuite();
        }
    }
```

it works, but eagerly. I would like to use `super.onBackPressed()` in `FragmentActivityContainer` but since back to previous fragment is in the middle between menu close and prompt quite, there is no way for me to do that. What is the best solution to solve this dependency problem?

Comment: could you elaborate "Back the previous fragment if changed fragments in content area"